# Дублирование записей MySQL без потери производительности

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с товарами в инет-магазине. 
Каждый товар после оформления заказа кладется в корзину, где его стоимость (и другие параметры) замораживаются. 
Сейчас эта заморозка сделана в виде json-строки с первоначальными параметрами, что не является лучшим выходом.

Упрощенно:

```
products:
id, name, price, description, update_date

cart:
cart_id, product_id, old_parameters, create_date
```

Если create_date корзины позже, чем дата последнего обновления товара, данные берутся из таблицы товаров. Если меньше - из JSON.

**Существует ли человеческий способ реализовать то же самое?**

P.S. Еще есть идея завести таблицу products_history и в ней хранить все значения для товаров за все время. Но она по структуре, а часто и данным будет очень похожа на основную таблицу товаров.
Хранить все в одной таблице не нахожу рациональным.

Comment: Просьба поправить заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна история редактирования товаров.
Добавляете поле is_actual.
При редактировании его ставим в 0, а новую строку добавляем с 1.
(Ну или можно от обратного идти и is_deleted сделать.)
id товара, естественно, меняется в каталоге товаров, а в заказах ссылаетесь на старые строки.

Comment: В таком случае будет разрастание таблицы товаров при любом редактировании(т.е. либо проверять активные ссылки на товар, либо смириться с новой строкой даже при изменении одной буквы), придется заводить ДВА поля ID - ID товара и ID версии, причем из корзины обращаться именно к версии.

Впрочем, старые версии можно чистить отдельным скриптом, если на них не указывает ни одна корзина.

Answer (score 1):

Надо просто в заказе хранить цену, и все. В корзине отображать цену из каталога, а в момент оформления заказа из каталога цена переносится в заказ, и все, никаких историй больше не нужно и проверок на изменения цен тоже. Самый простой вариант.

Comment: Да, вариант подойдет, если изменяется только цена. Хотелось бы хранить остальные данные, чтобы избежать недоразумений, когда хитропопый манагер приписал несуществующие достоинства.

Comment: @knes, как у вас все сложно. Ну да, вариант с сохранением всех возможных параметров в json тоже нормальный. Просто сохранять его в заказе, а не в корзине. Проверки просто не нужны. В заказах выводите из json, в корзине всегда из каталога.